# Test methods for the Soql in the extension class

Tags: apex

I am stuck with writing the test methods for the following class. I did start with the test methods but need help to get the records using the soql. Any help in finishing the test method is greatly appreciated. Thx.

```
public with sharing class active_selling_agreements_extension {
    private List<Opportunity> oppz;
    public Contact cntact; 
    public active_selling_agreements_extension (ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.cntact= (Contact)controller.getRecord();
    }
    public List<Opportunity> getagreements()
    {
        Contact con = [Select id, Account.Parent.id FROM Contact where id = :cntact.id];

        oppz = [Select id, Name, Account.Name, StageName, CloseDate, Amount, Type from Opportunity 
            where StageName = 'Active'  and isdeleted= false and  (Account.id = :con.Account.Parent.id or Account.id = :con.Account.id) ];
        return oppz;
    }

  /*Test Methods */
@isTest
public static void testactive_selling_agreements_extension(){

    Contact c = new Contact(name='Tester');
    ApexPages.StandardController controller = new ApexPages.StandardController(contact);
    active_selling_agreements_extension stdController = new active_selling_agreements_extension(controller);
    system.assert(stdController != null);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You test your SOQL by providing test data (see [why you shouldn't use real data](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8558/when-testing-can-i-not-use-existing-data/8562).) There are many [examples](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods) of how to provide test data to work with, but the short version is that test class or method needs to insert dummy data and then the test can verify the correct data was retrieved by your SOQL.