# Test Class Code Coverage Issue : System.QueryException

Tags: apex, unit-test

My Apex class is

Class1:

```
Public class myclass{
    //some code
    public void save(){
        invoice_policy__c inp=[select net__c,Internal_alerts__c,Send_Email__c,Email_Alerts__c,Send_To__c from invoice_policy__c where id=:selectin]; //getting error here
        if(inp.Internal_alerts__c == true){
             //some code
        }
    }
    string Selectin;
    Public string getSelectin(){return Selectin;}
    public void setSelectin(string selectin){this.selectin = Selectin;}

    public list<selectoption> getselectname(){
        list<selectoption> option = new list<selectoption>();  

        for(Invoice_Policy__c invoice : [select id,name,Policy_Status__c from Invoice_Policy__c where Policy_Status__c='Active'] ){       

            option.add(new selectoption(invoice.Id,invoice.name));
            system.debug('invocenameee'+invoice.Id);  
        }
        return option;     
    } 
}
```

My test class is

```
invoice_policy__c ip = new invoice_policy__c(name='TestPolicy',net__c='3',Policy_Status__c='Active',send_to__c='test@gmail.com',Email_Alerts__c='Before',Internal_Alerts__c =true);
ip.send_email__c='2';
insert ip;
system.debug('testttt'+ip);

myclass ic = new myclass();
ic.getselectin();
ic.setselectin('a0Wi0000000NMqbEAG');
ic.save();
```

Getting error as System.QueryException List has no rows for assignment to SObject
Help on this please.

Comment: you dont want to rely on setAllData, better setup your own data. but besides that, what does the following print out to the console? 

public class myclass2{

     public void myMethod1(string strid,string invoiceid){
      invoice__c invoice=[select Name,guid__c,invoice_contact__c,status__C from invoice__c where id=:invoiceid];
      system.debug('###invoice=' + invoice);
      ...
     }
}

Comment: If I don'y use seealldata=true,getting QueryException somewhere else in my code.Whatever Id I'm passing in my first class `myclass` those related fields are displayed in `Invoice`

Comment: Unit tests should exercise your methods as users would; why not just mimic the normal program flow?

Comment: On why `seealldata=true` is a bad idea: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/8562/142

Comment: @Seb__Wagner edited my code.Can u pls check

Comment: Why are you setting selectin to a hardcoded ID field?  ic.setselectin('a0Wi0000000NMqbEAG');  in a testmethod you should never refer to hard coded IDs. Seems like you want ic.setselectin(ip.id)

Answer (score 4):

As crop1645 in the comments pointed out, you're hard-coding an Id into your test that does not represent the object you just inserted.

In general though,

```
System.QueryException List has no rows for assignment to SObject
```

can be avoided by selecting to a list and then doing a check as to whether the list contains any objects. You can use that to either gracefully handle this condition or to surface a custom, and perhaps more descriptive exception to be handled elsewhere.